# How can I answer this Putnam question more rigorously?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, contest-math

> Given real numbers $a_0, a_1, ..., a_n$ such that $\dfrac {a_0}{1} + \dfrac {a_1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac {a_n}{n+1}=0,$ prove that $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n=0$ has at least one real solution.

My solution:

---

Let $$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n$$

$$\int f(x) = \dfrac {a_0}{1} x + \dfrac {a_1}{2}x^2 + \cdots + \dfrac {a_n}{n+1} x^{n+1} + C$$

$$\int_0^1 f(x) = \left[ \dfrac {a_0}{1} + \dfrac {a_1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac {a_n}{n+1} \right]-0$$

$$\int_0^1 f(x) = 0$$

Since $f$ is continuous, by the area interpretation of integration, it must have at least one zero.

---

My question is, is this rigorous enough? Do I need to prove the last statement, perhaps by contradiction using Riemann sums? Is this a theorem I can/should quote?

Comment: There's a standard lemma that if $f$ is a strictly positive (negative) function, then $\int f$ is strictly positive (negative). I suppose you could prove this easily with Riemann sums. Then apply the contrapositive to conclude that $f$ changes sign (or is identically zero), and invoke continuity.

Comment: I just want to complement you on your beautiful solution. Did you find it yourself ? What is your mathematical level (undergrad, grad school, etc)?

Comment: @user230452 Thank you very much. I did find it myself, but this problem was posed as a challenge in my calculus book in an integration chapter (Calculus by Larson/Edwards, $5^{th}$ ed., Page $346$ #$175$) so that was a giveaway. Once I saw that the integral had coefficients like the series, I remembered another problem I saw before somewhere else: "Find the sum of the coefficients of $f(x)=(x+3)^{30} (x+1)^{10}$". The answer is $4^{30} \cdot 2^{10}$; it is found by evaluating $f(1)$ (for any function). This led me to set one of the limits of integration to $1$, and $0$ was the first thing

Comment: @user230452 I tried for the other limit. I am an undergrad who just finished discrete math, I am about to start the more exciting classes like analysis and number theory :)

Comment: @Ovi Well done, Ovi ... Can you tell me which book you used for your discrete Math course ? Was it Kenneth Rosen or such ? I like discrete math a lot. Problems do become easier when you know their context, like you did here. Now that you've done it once, always look at a sum and ask yourself if the terms are the coefficients of a series of its derivative or integral. It's a common trick with sums and products. Keep up the hard work !

Comment: @Ovi Also, I recommend you start reading Ethan Bloch's book on real analysis before your course starts ! It really has powerful insight.

Comment: @user230452 Yup it was Kenneth Rosen. I didn't mean that discrete math wasn't fun (I will keep studying through it whenever I have time, there are many cool chapters we didn't cover), I am just happy to finally take upper-division math classes with other math majors. Thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind! I'll look for Ethan's book in the library. Are you a grad student yourself?

Comment: @Ovi Rosen's book is kind of boring with most of the exercises being mere drills. Laszlo Lovasz, and Nesetrjil both have two genuinely fun books on discrete mathematics. For combinatorics, I recommend Miklos Bona's Walk Through Combinatorics.

Comment: @Ovi You could just browse through Davenport's Higher Arithmetic in preparation for number theory, although what really inspired me for number theory is pretty much any collection of contest math books. Michael Rassias book is strongly recommended by me. If I were you, I'd browse through Rassias and Blouch before your courses start.

Comment: @Ovi All the best and Let me know if you need any help regarding book recommendations :)

Comment: @user230452 I will look those up at the library, thanks!

Comment: @user230452 Let me take you up on that offer of reccomending books :). I looked up Laszlo Lovasz's Discrete Math book, and you were right some of the exercises were fun. But in general I am not a big fan of the combinatorics topics covered in that book.  Do you know of any good introductory books on reccurance relations and/or functional equations? Also, I would like to know if you have any reccomandations on problem solving books. I tried out Arthur Engel's book, but found it to  be slightly too difficult for me. Additionally, I'm afraid the book is not very instructive either in (t.b.c)

Comment: @user230452 (continued) how to solve problems. I showed one of the problems to one of my professors, and he solved it in a very natural way. But the solution presented in the book relied on just seeing a very contrived algebraic relationship, to which even my professor said "What, did he pull that out of the hat? I can guarantee the author didn't initially solve the problem this way".

Comment: @Ovi I'd like to answer your question ... But comments is a bit short and I don't know if I can post it as an answer because it's not about the question asked in the title. Let me know if there's any other way I can PM you or send you a mail.

Comment: @Ovi Sorry for the delay, I'll send you a mail tomorrow.

Comment: @user230452 No problem, I appreciate the help!

Comment: I sent a mail. But it bounced. Will try again today.

Comment: @user230452 Thanks, if it bounces again I can provide another address.

Comment: @user230452 Did you get my reply?

Comment: @Ovi Haha. No. I was actually wondering if you got my mail. Lol

Comment: @user230452 Haha I don't know what is wrong with these email providers, I didn't even get a "Failed to Send" notification. I sent the original reply on Jan 12. I just sent it again right now, please let me know if its not in your inbox the next time you check

Comment: Yeah ... I checked again and saw your mails went to the spam folder so I didn't get notified. I fixed it now. Sorry for the inconvenience. Will reply soon.

Comment: @user230452 Oh okay no problem

Comment: @Ovi hope you got my reply

Comment: @user230452 Hmm I didn't, when did you send it?

Comment: I got a failure daemon mail ... I'll resend it today evening.

Comment: @user230452 Perhaps creating a private chatroom on MSE would be a more reliable means of communication?

Comment: @user230452 Yes I did, sorry I've been really busy with classes.I will reply this weekend. You gave me some math problems to solve so I can't reply so fast :)

Comment: @user230452 Hey, sorry I didn't have time to reply this weekend, I will definitely try to reply in the next few days.

Comment: @Ovi Hey ... Did you send it ?

Comment: @user230452 Hi, I'm sorry for the delay; I've already started woking on the reply, and I'll absolutely send it tomorrow at the latest.

Comment: @user230452 Hi, I just sent it. Did you recieve it?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Why not write it the other way round?

The polynomial function 
$$F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{k+1}x^{k+1} $$
is a differentiable function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with derivative $$F'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k.$$
We are given that $F(1)=0$, and clearly $F(0)=0$. Hence by [**Rolle's theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), there exists $x\in(0,1)$ such that $F'(x)=0$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Indeed, this is the rigorous proof of the area-interpretation described in the OP.

Answer (score 18):

Your proof looks fine. If you wanted to expand, you could add the following:

> Suppose $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.  Then we must have 
>   $$\int_0^1f(x)\ dx>0,$$
>   But we have already shown that $\int_0^1f(x)\ dx=0$, a contradiction.
>
> If we assume $f(x)<0$ for all $x>0$, we arrive at a similar contradiction.

Answer (score 13):

You can also prove it using the mean value theorem. You showed that $$\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx=0
 $$ now since $f$ is continuous by the [mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Definite_Integrals) we have that exists some $c\in\left(0,1\right)
 $ such that $$f\left(c\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx
 $$ so $$f\left(c\right)=0$$ as wanted.